# How to draw asterisks triangles side by side with c

Tags: c

I wanted to draw 4 different triangles horizontally side by side
[the output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu8ZP.jpg)

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
  
 int main(void) 
 {       
     while ( 1 ) 
     { 
         printf( "Enter a number (0 to exit): " ); 
          
         int n; 
          
         if ( ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 ) || ( n == 0 ) ) break; 
          
         putchar( '\n' ); 
         for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
         { 
             for ( int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ ) printf("*"); 
             putchar( '\n' ); 
         } 
         putchar( '\n' ); 
     } 
 }
```

this code only prints one triangle, any idea how to progress further?

Comment: Find a pattern: how many asterisks are in each triangle for each line and how many spaces are between them? How do they depend on line number? Then print sequences of required number of asterisks and spaces for all triangles in each line.

Comment: Simply put, you need to keep track of 4 pairs of values for each line (presuming all triangles to be the same width and height). How many stars and how many spaces to print **on this row** for each triangle. Then, some numbers increase, and some decrease. (If you are clever, you could use **one** number for each triangle and use "width - n" to specify the other number...)

Comment: Quick question: Is this a homework assignment? If so, please post more of your attempted solutions toward getting "4-up" triangles. SO answers are not intended to help you get grades for work that you did not do yourself.

Comment: Side note: The correct `scanf` conversion format specifier for `int` is `%d`, not `%u`. The specifier `%u` should only be used with `unsigned int`. However, in your case, it will probably work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the other answers has already provided a solution for printing all 4 triangles below each other.

However, in order to print them side by side, as you are asking for, you will have to print all 4 triangles at the same time, for example like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_stars( int num_stars )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_stars; i++ )
    {
        putchar( '*' );
    }
}

void print_blanks( int num_blanks )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < num_blanks; i++ )
    {
        putchar( ' ' );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        int n;

        //get input from user
        printf( "Enter a number (0 to exit): " );
        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 )
            break;

        //add spacing
        printf( "\n" );

        //draw all n lines
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            //print segment of first triangle
            print_stars( i + 1 );
            print_blanks( n - i - 1 );

            //print spacing
            printf( "   " );

            //print segment of second triangle
            print_stars( n - i );
            print_blanks( i );

            //print spacing
            printf( "   " );

            //print segment of third triangle
            print_blanks( i );
            print_stars( n - i );

            //print spacing
            printf( "   " );

            //print segment of fourth triangle
            print_blanks( n - i - 1 );
            print_stars( i + 1 );

            //end the line
            printf( "\n" );
        }

        //add spacing
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
Enter a number (0 to exit): 1

*   *   *   *

Enter a number (0 to exit): 2

*    **   **    *
**   *     *   **

Enter a number (0 to exit): 3

*     ***   ***     *
**    **     **    **
***   *       *   ***

Enter a number (0 to exit): 4

*      ****   ****      *
**     ***     ***     **
***    **       **    ***
****   *         *   ****

Enter a number (0 to exit): 5

*       *****   *****       *
**      ****     ****      **
***     ***       ***     ***
****    **         **    ****
*****   *           *   *****

Enter a number (0 to exit): 6

*        ******   ******        *
**       *****     *****       **
***      ****       ****      ***
****     ***         ***     ****
*****    **           **    *****
******   *             *   ******

Enter a number (0 to exit): 7

*         *******   *******         *
**        ******     ******        **
***       *****       *****       ***
****      ****         ****      ****
*****     ***           ***     *****
******    **             **    ******
*******   *               *   *******

Enter a number (0 to exit): 8

*          ********   ********          *
**         *******     *******         **
***        ******       ******        ***
****       *****         *****       ****
*****      ****           ****      *****
******     ***             ***     ******
*******    **               **    *******
********   *                 *   ********

Enter a number (0 to exit): 9

*           *********   *********           *
**          ********     ********          **
***         *******       *******         ***
****        ******         ******        ****
*****       *****           *****       *****
******      ****             ****      ******
*******     ***               ***     *******
********    **                 **    ********
*********   *                   *   *********

Enter a number (0 to exit): 0
```

Note that your terminal/console may be configured to wrap lines if they are too long. Therefore, you may have to change the configuration of your terminal/console so that the maximum line size is sufficiently large, if you want to display large numbers of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

the first diagram you already did it by yourself

- for the **second diagram**, change:

  ```
  for ( int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ ) printf("*");
  ```

into

```
for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) printf("*");
```

- for the **third diagram**, change:

  ```
  for ( int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ ) printf("*");
  ```

into

```
for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
   if(j >= i)
       printf("*");
   else
       printf(" ");
```

- for the **fourth diagram**, change:

  ```
  for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
  { 
      for ( int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ ) printf("*"); 
      putchar( '\n' ); 
  }
  ```

into

```
  for ( int i = n; i >= 0; i-- )
  {
      for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
         if(j >= i)
             printf("*");
         else
             printf(" ");
        putchar( '\n' );
  }
```

and this is a full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a number (0 to exit): " );

        int n;

        if ( ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 ) || ( n == 0 ) ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++ ) printf("*");
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        putchar( '\n' );
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = i; j < n; j++ ) printf("*");
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        putchar( '\n' );
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                if(j >= i)
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );


        putchar( '\n' );
        for ( int i = n; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
                if(j >= i)
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            putchar( '\n' );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

    }
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Enter a number (0 to exit):10

*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
**********


**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*


**********
 *********
  ********
   *******
    ******
     *****
      ****
       ***
        **
         *



         *
        **
       ***
      ****
     *****
    ******
   *******
  ********
 *********
**********
```

Comment: thanks alot, but is there anyways we can arrange it side by side?

Comment: @Varick, yes it could be done but it would a very tedious process as you can only print line by line , so you will have one big loop with many conditions in it to see whether to print an "*" here or not and checl for which graph of the 4 graphs we are printing the star for

Answer (score 1):

To avoid giving away too much, here are the rudiments of a tiny program that produced the output shown below. (Yes, this is all the lines of code that are needed.)

If you can manage to fill in the blanks, you might get very good marks on this assignment!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 7;
    char *p = "********....
    char *pa[4] = { p + ....

    for( int r = 1; r <= n; r++ ) {
        for( int t = 0; t < 4; t++ ) {
            printf( "%....
            pa[t] += t%2 ? ....
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
*        *******  *******        *
**       ******    ******       **
***      *****      *****      ***
****     ****        ****     ****
*****    ***          ***    *****
******   **            **   ******
*******  *              *  *******
```

**EDIT:**
At the recommendation of an SO regular with more SO experience than me, here is the full (but limited) version of that code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 7;
    char *p = "**********          **********",
         *pa[] = { p + 9, p + 10 - n, p + 20, p + 21 - n };

    for( int r = 1; r <= n; r++ ) {
        for( int t = 0; t < 4; t++ ) {
            printf( "%.*s  ", n, pa[t] );
            pa[t] += t%2 ? 1 : -1;
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, this works in the range of 1-10 stars/spaces. To achieve 1-n, this could be extended to allocate a buffer on the heap, fill it with n stars and n spaces and n stars (as a string), then twiddle the hardcoded initial offsets in pa[] to account for those larger offsets.

**EDIT2:**
Playing with this idea, one can exploit the printf format specifier to reduce the requirements of the string that is used as raw material. And, while we're at it, factor the function out of main so that it can be iterated independently, this time up to the value of 15 wide/high.

```
void fun( int n ) {
    char *p = "               ***************"; // 15x' ' + 15x '*'

    // the 15/30-ish-ness of the following should be apparent
    char *pa[] = { p + 15+15-1, p + 15+15-n, p + 15, p + 15+1-n };

    for( int r = 1; r <= n; r++ ) {
        for( int t = 0; t < 4; t++ ) {
            printf( "%-*.*s  ", n, n, pa[t] );
            pa[t] += t%2 ? 1 : -1;
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main() {
    for( int i = 1; i <= 15; i++ ) {
        printf( "\n%d:\n", i );
        fun( i );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If pointer arithmetic is not understood as yet, two lines of the code above can be changed to use array indexing instead:

```
//  char *pa[] = { p + 15+15-1, p + 15+15-n, p + 15, p + 15+1-n }; // THIS...
    int pa[] = { 15+15-1, 15+15-n, 15, 15+1-n }; // becomes this.

// and

//          printf( "%-*.*s  ", n, n, pa[t] ); // THIS...
            printf( "%-*.*s  ", n, n, &p[ pa[t] ] ); // becomes this.
```

Comment: Although it is generally a good idea to not immediately provide the full solution to a homework assignment, in this case, I believe it is acceptable to immediately provide the full solution, because OP has already gotten quite far.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Done! Let the DV'ing begin!!! `:-)`

Comment: I don't think that OP has already learnt about pointer arithmetic yet, so they will probably be unable to understand your solution. However, I am still upvoting your answer, because answers on Stack Overflow are not only written for the benefit of the original posters; they are written for all readers.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thank you! `:-)` Re: "pointer arithmetic" - I understand. This could be easily adapted to simply use array offsets instead of initialised pointers that incr-/decr-ment... Jollies on a slow day `:-)`